# MySQL connection in CakePHP -> Why do I keep getting the 30 seconds exceeded fatal error?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, fatal-error

Here is a snippet of the code I got from some tutorial blog:

```
<?php
class PersonalBlogController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'PersonalBlog';
    var $uses = array('PersonalBlog');

    function index(){
        //ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
        debug($this->PersonalBlog->findAll());
        //debug($this->PersonalBlog->find('all'));
    }
}?>
```

I have seen some other cases in max time limit fatal error from other posts. But mine is probably the most disgusting. The fatal 30 secs time limit error keeps coming even after I change the max_execution_time variable in php.ini. Even after changing it to 60 or 300 seconds, the error message stays the same. It says 30 seconds time limit is exceeded.

I then followed alternative solution from a similar question, which is to do this instead:`ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` (See my commented code above).

The error is gone. However what happens after that is this:

Warning (2): PDO::__construct(): [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not  (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php, line 155]
.....
.....blablabla...
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in C:\Server\www\myserver.dev\public_html\cakephp-cakephp-7fbf7a4\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php on line 259

So I realized that I actually have two MySQL server installed. The newest one (5.5.11) is on port 3307 not on port 3306! That is why I then changed my driver setting in the dbo_mysql.php:

```
/**
 * Base configuration settings for MySQL driver
 *
 * @var array
 */
    protected $_baseConfig = array(
        'persistent' => true,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'mysqlpassword',
        'database' => 'personal_blog',
        'port' => '3307'
    );
```

Every other setting is normal; I have the same database setting for app>config>database file as you can see here:

```
public $default = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'mysqlpassword',
        'database' => 'personal_blog',
            'port' => 3307,
        'prefix' => '',
    );
```

After those changes, the warning still appears...I really feel like I want to throw up right now

Any help would be appreciated.thx

Comment: In the error message text, I think you've missed something: `...party did not (trying`. Is there some text between `not` and `(trying`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to edit the dbo_config to manage the port setting. All of those keys are available for use in the database.php file in your app/config/ folder.

You actually shouldn't have your personal defaults in the dbo file *at all* -- nothing you are doing should ever edit any core files.

Once you have your port setting in ONLY the database.php file and your dbo driver is back to the one that shipped with cake you should delete all of the files in /tmp/cache and set your debug > 0 in app/config/core.php

Refresh and if the error is still occurring we know that something is messed up at the php.ini / .htaccess or ini_set level. Try adjusting the value and then loading a view that contains

```
<?php
    phpinfo( );
?>
```

and see if the max execution time setting is actually being read by the php interpreter. If it isn't you might want to try the ini set method or htaccess methods of playing with that value. Also make sure the php.ini you are editing is the right one ( the path to the ini should be in the php info dump ) - you might find you have 2 versions of php loaded as well as your two versions of mysql.

If that doesn't solve or at least pinpoint the issue then post back here and let us know.

Comment: So now I have had everything re-setup. but how can I load the content of index.ctp in view if theres an error? inside my cakephp-cakephp home directory i have app,cake,plugins,vendor, .htacess,etc. But from my understanding of this framework, http://localhost/cakephp-cakephp/personalblog/index or something like that means it will pull the data out from the view automatically even if there is no folder/directory called personalblog defined in home directory. is that right?

Comment: oh and I think I forgot to tell you that on my cakephp welcome page localhost/cakephp-cakephp, there is no CSS style at all which means mod_rewrite in my system isnt working. in addition to that, what cake told me on the welcome message is that "database configuration is present" which is right. BUT there is no message saying "cake is able to connect to database" like what i see on normal cases...

Comment: You should test a fresh install - and make sure your VirtualHost directive has the DocumentRoot set to the <app>/webroot folder. I typically **don't** have an app folder as I use the domain name as the folder name with the config / controllers / webroot / etc inside of that folder directly. It sounds like you have a path / DocumentRoot / htaccess issue.